# Sum the values when siblings nodes are repeated in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I have a sequence of nested nodes and I'm attempting to find the repeated dates (considering only year and month) of the `due_date` nodes in each `loan` and then sum the values of their sibling nodes (`amount`).
An example explains better.

File `payments.xml`:

```
<loan>
 <id>1</id>
 <payments>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2012-11-28T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>484</amount>
    </local_payment>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2012-12-05T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>450</amount>
    </local_payment>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2012-12-12T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>484</amount>
    </local_payment>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2012-01-19T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>450</amount>
    </local_payment>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2012-01-26T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>450</amount>
    </local_payment>
 </payments>
</loan>
<loan>
  <id>2</id>
  <payments>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2013-02-02T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>500</amount>
    </local_payment>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2013-02-09T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>500</amount>
    </local_payment>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2013-03-16T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>600</amount>
    </local_payment>
    <local_payment>
        <due_date>2013-04-23T08:00:00Z</due_date>
        <amount>650</amount>
    </local_payment>
  </payments>
</loan>
```

I have already wrote a simple function to extract only the year and month, but I don't know how do the rest.
The expected output should be without repeated dates for each loan and with their amounts  added up.

Comment: I just answered your questions, but your questions actually could need improvement. For XML/Xquery questions it is always useful to post your expected output, as it is currently unclear what exactly you want (what does "without repeated dates" mean, in my answer I still output the repeated dates...). Also, if you already wrote something please include it into your question, even if it fails - It only to show your effort. Last, but not least: Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you very much @dirkk for the fast reply. Sorry, next time I will make my question following your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wonderful example for the XQuery 3.0 construct of [group by](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by), so I am going to assume that your XQuery processor supports 3.0.

You can group based on such a year/month condition (there are built in functions to get the month and year of dateTime, so no need to write your own). Then you can compute the sum using `sum()`.

However, XQuery is a querying language and not intended to update existing data, so you will have to reconstruct the data. As you didn't exactly specify how you want to have your resulting output structure I took my own approach - Adapt as needed.

```
for $loan in /loan
return 
  <loan>
  { $loan/id }
  <payments>{
    for $payment in $loan/payments/local_payment
    let $year-month := month-from-dateTime($payment/due_date) || year-from-dateTime($payment/due_date)
    group by $year-month
    return <local_payment>
      { $payment/due_date }
      <amount>{ sum($payment/amount) }</amount>
    </local_payment>

  }</payments></loan>
```

Comment: It is what I needed. This data will be stored in an output file and then I will use them for a compare with other data.
Thank you , now I know the group by statement and to have only distinct date I'll use the distinct-values function.

Comment: My function to retrieve only month and year is this: 
`declare function local:year-month ( $seq as node()* ) as xs:string {
  for $i in $seq 
  return substring($i, 1, 7) 
} ;`
and I use it to show only distinct date in this way:
`...... 
return <local_payment>
      { distinct-values($payment/local:year-month(due_date)) }
      <amount>{ sum($payment/amount) }</amount>
    </local_payment>
  ` 
Is it correct or is there an other way? Thank you

Comment: **Always** use built-in functions instead of writing your own. As I said, there are built-in functions for getting the month and year from a dateTime in XQuery, so instead of using some substring just use this (take a look at `2012-12-31T17:00:00-07:00`). Especially for dates this is relevant, as date calculation is incredibly hard. For example, the valid dateTimes `2012-12-31T17:00:00-07:00` and `2013-01-01T00:00:00Z` are actually the same, but would have a different year and month using your function.